# Convert schema evolving (SCD) JSON/XML into ORC/Parquet format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, orc

We are getting varieties of JSONs/XMLs as input where schema is always evolving. I want to process them using ORC or Parquet format in Hadoop/Hive environment for performance gain.

I know below common style of achieving same objective :
Use JSONSerde or XMLSerde library, first create hive table using these serde. Later select * fields query will be fired on each xml/json hive table to save as orc or save as parquet into another table. Once done successful I can drop these Serde Table and XML/JSON data.

What would be another good ways of doing same ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by you, this is the most common way to do an offline conversion of JSON/XML data to parquet format.
But another way could be to parse the JSON/XML and create Parquet Groups for each of the JSON records. Essentially:

Open the JSON file
 Read each individual record 
 Open another file 
 Create a Parquet Group from the record read in #2
 Write the parquet group to the file created in #3
 Do this for all records in the file
 Close both files.

We came up with such a converter for one of our used case.